# spock possible bug?

Tags: groovy, spock

Here're some of my base interfaces:

```
public interface ParsingService {
   boolean isQualifiedNode(Resource resource)
}

interface IndexBuilder {
    boolean buildSingleResource(Resource resource)
}


// An OSGI component. Also an implementation for IndexBuilder
@Component(
    immediate = true
)
@Service
class SolrIndexBuilder implements IndexBuilder {
  List<ParsingService> parsers 

    @Override
    public boolean buildSingleResource(Resource subject) {
        boolean success = true
        SolrClient client = serverConfiguration.getSolrClient()

        for (ParsingService parser : parsers) {
            try{
                if(parser.isQualifiedNode(subject)) {
                    client.commit()
                }
                else {
                    log.debug(" ${subject.path} not qualified for parsing by parser: ${parser.serviceSummary}")
                    continue //continue to trying the next parser
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                success = false
                log.error("error while parsing resource: ${subject} by parser: ${parser.serviceSummary}")
                continue //continue to trying the next parser
            }
        }
        return success
    }
}
```

And here's the corresponding spock unit-test

```
class SolrIndexBuilderSpecification extends Specification {
    SolrIndexBuilder indexBuilder
    SolrClient mockClient = Mock()
    SolrServerConfiguration mockServerConfiguration = Mock()
    ParsingService parser = Mock()
    ParsingService parser_page = Mock()
    ParsingService parser_asset = Mock()

    def setup(){
        indexBuilder = new SolrIndexBuilder()
        mockServerConfiguration.getSolrClient() >> mockClient
    }

    def "testing buildSingleResource: only parsers who qualify a node, will process the node under scrutiny"() {
        setup:
        Resource pageResource = Mock()
        parser.isQualifiedNode(_) >> false
        parser_page.isQualifiedNode(_) >> true  // WHY does this not return true in method under test? 
        indexBuilder.parsers = Arrays.asList(parser,parser_page)

        when:
        indexBuilder.buildSingleResource(pageResource)

        then:
        1 * parser.isQualifiedNode(pageResource)
        1 * parser_page.isQualifiedNode(pageResource)
        /*
         * TODO: Troubleshoot below when you have the time.
         * Parser is supposed to invoke mockClient.commit() call once. So the invocation clause:
         *   1 * mockClienct.commit()
         *
         * should yield true.  However, that doesn't hold. Instead the invocation clause:
         *   0 * mockClient.commit()
         *
         * holds true. 
         */
        0 * mockClient.commit()  // SHOULDN"T BE !! One of the parsers should return true for 'isQualifiedNode(..)'
    }
}
```

As you can see in the test under investigation: I have two Mocks for the 'ParsingService' interface defined. They are 'parser' and 'parser_page'. Also, one of them is designed to return true when .isQualifiedNode(..) method is called. However, for BOTH of them, only false is returned. WHY ? Can someone try to recreate this. The more I look, the more I'm convinced it is a bug, unless I don't understand fundamental about spock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of

```
    parser.isQualifiedNode(_) >> false
    parser_page.isQualifiedNode(_) >> true
```

And change

```
    1 * parser.isQualifiedNode(pageResource)
    1 * parser_page.isQualifiedNode(pageResource)
```

To

```
    1 * parser.isQualifiedNode(pageResource) >> false
    1 * parser_page.isQualifiedNode(pageResource) >> true
```

Comment: Thanks that works... Not sure, why this is the way it is, but I also found this written in the spock documentations.